# Graphene as optical and UV mirrors

Tags: laser, thermal-radiation, space-travel, graphene

One usually hears about graphene as a good thermal conductor, and good light absorber due to its tunable bandgap properties. But i haven't heard about its aplicability as an optical mirror. In fact, mostly the opposite is true: the optical transmissivity of monolayer graphene is very high ($\approx$ 98%)

Since there are material engineering tricks to tune the separation between two or more graphene layers, i would expect that multi-layer destructive interference can be achieved with optical wavelengths, enhancing reflectivity

I know that probably graphene is not the best material to do this, but allow me to insist. Why? Well, graphene mantains it's properties well over 3000K, and a couple of layers of it can be quite strong and very light. All these properties make it the ideal material for a laser-pushed sail.

By the way, i'm asking about optical and UV frequencies, i know that monolayer graphene is reflective on the microwave region, and i'm not asking about that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There has been some research in the use of graphene in optics, such as from [Berkeley's Ultrafast Nano Optics Group](http://blogs.ls.berkeley.edu/fengwang/research/graphene/) and [this article about the use of graphene in digitl communications](http://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1009/1009.4465.pdf).

In terms of graphene's UV and visual reflective properties, according to the [University of Manchester](http://www.graphene.manchester.ac.uk/story/properties/) and ["High optical absorbance of graphene"](http://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1201/1201.3071.pdf), it is graphene's absorbance properties that quite unique - with a one atom sheet having 2.3% absorbance in the visual range.  For both the visual and UV range, [this OptisInfobase article](http://www.opticsinfobase.org/oe/fulltext.cfm?uri=oe-19-23-23111&id=224068) go into far more detail (with data).